# How to retain printsetup using VBA

Tags: vba

I am copying some cells with  original formatting to a different spreadsheet 
I must retain printset up

```
Set res = .Offset(2).Resize(lastrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                If Not res Is Nothing Then

                    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

                    wb.Worksheets.Add.Name = "report"



                   With wb.Worksheets("report")
                        rngHeader.Copy Destination:=.Range("A5")
                        res.Copy Destination:=.Range("A6")
                    End With
```

However the newly created spreadsheet does not preserve the `Print Settings`

I need to set

1) Orientation Landscape
2) Custom margins .3 everythwere[image]

How can i do this using vba

Comment: Check out **[PageSetup Members (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841253(v=office.14).aspx)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "Print Settings" you actually mean "Page Setup", then refer to `PageSetup` object belonging to each sheet (e.g. `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).PageSetup.FooterMargin`) – you'll find all settings there. You should be able to easily copy them from **Sheet1** to **Sheet2**, setting by setting. If you need further help, please let me know,

Comment: +1 Thank you miroxlav ! This is waht i was looking for . Ideally , I wanted to immitate the exact same `PageSetup` from one sheet to another . I can set it separately but , how to immitate them ? How can I do this ?

Comment: Is it OK for you just to copy the settings? I mean something like

`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).PageSetup.FooterMargin = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).PageSetup.FooterMargin`

which copies setting *FooterMargin* from Sheet #1 to Sheet #2. Similar for all other settings.